# Firestore write behavior, partial document write

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to get a better understanding on how writes to Firestore take place in case a client's internet connection might be intermittent.

I know there's batch writes for instances when you want to update multiple docs for an all or nothing write.

What I wanted to know is if I'm writing to a single document that has let's say 30 fields. Is Firestore write an all or nothing write per document or could there be a case where only part of the 30 fields update whereas the others fail due to internet issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A document write is all or nothing.  It's not possible for a document to end up partially written in any circumstance.